# connect sql2005 database from vc++

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I want to connect my application with sql server2005 express and my application on vs2008.

the connection string is:

```
db.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, _T("ODBC;Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=ESS10\SQLEXPRESS;Database=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\\testingsql.mdf;Trusted_Connection=yes;")))
```

but when I debug the code the pop box open.

[image]
 Any one suggest that how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It says, Named Pipes isnt enabled, check what options you have. Chances are tcp is enabled so you can do

Server=tcp:ESS10\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I have tried this but the error is same "TCP provider:No such host is know."

Comment: If ESS10 is your local machine try .\SQLEXPRESS (without the tcp), and also check your sqlexpress is running, check what conneciton options are available.